# Is it possible to pass a Javascript function parameter to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know that PHP is a Server-Side and Javascript is Client-side , But I'm wondering if it's possible to do the following .

I have a javascript function that calls an Ajax call to a PHP file , Here is the code:

```
function reloadData(fileName){
    $.ajax({
        //I want to insert the fileName parameter before .php
        url: '<?php echo $filePath ."/fileName.php";?>',
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        success: function( data ){ 
            //Do Some Thing With Returned Data. 
        }
    });
}
```

I want to pass PHP file name to the reloadData function

```
reloadData('get_data');
```

So that the url within ajax will be:

```
url: 'get_data.php',
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Do like this, where you use the *filename* variable and split the url string like this `' + fileName + '`

```
function reloadData(fileName){
    $.ajax({
        //I want to insert the fileName parameter before .php
        url: '<?php echo $filePath ."/' + fileName + '.php";?>',
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        success: function( data ){ 
            //Do Some Thing With Returned Data. 
        }
    });
}
```

---

As a note though, when PHP echo this server side you might need to do something like this

```
'<?php echo $filePath ."/"?>' + filename + '.php'
```

Comment: Sorry I missed the PHP code within the url , Please review it now.

Comment: @jack Updated my answer

Comment: This is a good example where mixing languages causes color-coding to go wonky.

Comment: @IncredibleHat True :)

Answer (score 1):

Set your filepath as a global variable in your js so that you can make use of it throught you code. Then make use of this variable like this in your function:

```js
var filePath = "<?php echo $filePath ?>/";

function reloadData(fileName){
    $.ajax({
        //I want to insert the fileName parameter before .php
        url: filePath + fileName.trim() + '.php',
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        success: function( data ){ 
            //Do Some Thing With Returned Data. 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry I missed the PHP code within the url , Please review it now.

Comment: I generally go with this method, as this single-line can be put almost anywhere, and then you can have the bulk of the .js as an include file. Another option is to put data into a hidden input somewhere with an id and pull it by jQ selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
url: 'fileName.php',
```

To:

```
url: `${fileName}.php`,
```

Comment: Sorry I missed the PHP code within the url , Please review it now.